# How to use java code to mock mysql charset conversion?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I'm using java program to mock charset conversion during executing sql command in mysql client.For example:

```
mysql> show variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                 |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | gbk                                   |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                |
| character_set_results    | gbk                                   |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                               |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                  |
| character_sets_dir       | /opt/mysql/server-5.6/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+---------------------------------------+
mysql> show create table t4\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
   Table: t4
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t4` (
`data` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
mysql> insert into t4 select '\U+1F600';
mysql> select data,hex(data) from t4;
+------+-----------+
| data | hex(data) |
+------+-----------+
| ??   | 3F3F      |
```

From mysql document(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html), it seems the data is first converted from my os charset(utf8) to client(gbk), then from gbk(client) to latin1(connection).
So based on the above understanding, I wrote a java test program to mock this unseen conversion. See below:

```
/**
* os utf-8
* character_set_client gbk
* character_set_connection latin1
* field latin1
* 
* @throws UnsupportedEncodingException 
*/
@Test
public void test_os_utf8_to_client_gbk_to_connection_latin1() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
    String emoji = "";
    String receivedStr = new String(emoji.getBytes("utf-8"),"gbk"); //os(utf-8)-->client(gbk)
    System.out.println(receivedStr);//馃榾
    String convertedStr = new String(receivedStr.getBytes("latin1"),"latin1"); //client(gbk) --> connection(latin1)
    System.out.println(convertedStr);//??
    printHexString(convertedStr.getBytes("latin1")); //3f 3f
```

}

Above code could get the same result as real mysql operation.
I'd like to know whether the principle behind this mock is correct or just happen to be right?

Answer (score 0):

is a 4-byte utf8 character.  In MySQL, it needs `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.  (The outside world calls it `utf8` or `UTF-8`, but MySQL has a distinction.)

`\U+1F600` also says that it will be 4 bytes in utf8, since it is bigger than FFFF.

`馃榾` can be rendered in MySQL's utf8 or utf8mb4.  It is hex `E9A683 E6A6BE`.

`latin1` is not a good MySQL `CHARACTER SET` for either case.  It can be used (though not the way you tried), but only because `latin1` fails to check the bytes for validity.  *All* 8-bit values have some meaning in latin1.  However, you might get `ðŸ˜€` for the emoji or `é¦ƒæ¦¾` for the pair of Chinese characters.

Your mixture of *six* `character%` settings is simply asking for trouble.  Try to start with the default, then change exactly three of them by using `SET NAMES`.  The 3 are `_client`, `_connection`, and `_results`.

The question marks came because:

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

The data cannot be retrieved from the table.

To do things correctly,

- utf8-encoded data (good)
- establish `utf8mb4` when in the connection from client to server
- check that the column(s) and/or table default are `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`
- If you are displaying on a web page, `<meta...charset=utf-8>` should be near the top.

(Two of those specify `utf8mb4` because they are talking to MySQL; the other two are the more generic `utf8`.)

You mentioned `gbk`.  If the bytes in the client are encoded for "gbk", then continue with this paragraph.  (I suspect they are not, since Java likes to deal with Unicode, hence utf8.)  It is OK to have `gbk` bytes in the client *if* you have established `SET NAMES gbk`.  This implies that gbk-encoded bytes will be transcoded to/from the `CHARACTER SET` of the table.  Note: `latin1` *cannot* hold Chinese characters, nor emoji, so `CHARACER SET latin1` is not a valid object.  `CHARACTER SET gbk` or `utf8mb4` should work.  (Moreover, I suspect that gbk cannot hold that emoji, so `utf8mb4` may be the only reasonable option, and `SET NAMES gbk` will probably not work.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggesting! But I do not ask for a good  practice. I want to know the mechanism behind the mysql charset. So I have to set diff charset in the process and observe the result for verifying my hypothesis.  Because I'm not very familiar with C++ and now by checking mysql source code to verify  it is a little hard for me. So I used java code to mock this. In fact I just want to know the mechanism of mysql charset conversion, that is this java code whether can express real mysql operation, or just happen to get the same result

Comment: I have spent years learning the "mechanism".  Most of what I know is in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).  What gave you in this answer was a condensation of it, tailored specifically to what you mentioned.  Since there are about _four_ "moving parts", it is quite challenging to experiment.